# What is the difference between a Gridview's DataKeys property and DataKeyNames?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

They seem to be equal.  Can both have multiple keys separated by a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are diffrent datakeysname are storing the name of the primay key column while datakeys will have the values for the that column.

See the following examples.
http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/87_Accessing_Invisible_Columns_of_GridView_Control.aspx

Answer (score 3):

DataKeyNames is where you specify the field names that comprise the key.  It's compound to support compound keys.

DataKeys stores the actual key values.

Comment: From the gridview markup, does it matter if I use DataKeys="PersonId,FirstName" or DataKeyNames="PersonId,FirstName"

Answer (score 0):

DataKeyNames:

Gets an array that contains the names of the primary key field of the currently displayed rows in the GridView.

DataKeys:

Gets a collection of DataKey objects that represent the value of the primary key fields set in DataKeyNames property of the GridView.